# Where does Magisk look for image files?

Tags: rooting, magisk

I'm attempting to root a Nexus 5x.  I've installed Magisk 25.2 but I don't know where to place the image file so that Magisk can find it.  When I select "Select and Patch a File", Magisk allows me to select from "Recent", "Audio", "Downloads", and "Photos".  Where are these folders on the file system so that I can move to the image file with `adb push`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you click the three dots in the top-right corner, you'll see the option "Show Internal Storage".  Once you click on that, the "Internal Storage" item will show up in the side bar.  Clicking on that, you'll see various subfolders which are contained in `/sdcard` (at least, on my phone).